# Ctrl+W in command mode deletes till space rather than deleting one word

Tags: vim

When I use `<c-w>` in command mode to delete a word, instead the whole WORD till the last space is being deleted. For example:

```
:e /var/www/hello
```

If I press `<c-w>`, then it leaves

```
:e
```

And I expected it to leave

```
:e /var/www/
```

This issue is only relevant for one of my saved sessions. I guess I accidentally changed an option I didn't want to change, and it was saved in the session. What is the option that defines the behavior of `<c-w>` in command mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't have `<c-w>` mapped to something else, [`<c-w>`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#c_CTRL-W) is influenced by the [`iskeyword`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27iskeyword%27) setting.  Mine is set as `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255`, and `<c-w>` works as expected.

Comment: Yup, it turns out I somehow got `iskeyword=@,48-57,_,192-255,*,/ ` in my `set iskeyword?`. Thank you very much.